# Spring Boot Application Throwing Error, But SQL Management Studio Works Fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application that interacts with a SQL database. When I execute a particular SQL query within my Spring Boot application, it throws an error, whereas when I execute the same query directly in SQL Management Studio, it works perfectly fine.

I'm puzzled by this discrepancy. Could someone shed some light on potential reasons why this might be happening? Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
  @Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "select *from( select *,ROUND(RAND(),0) as PrezzoListino,ROUND(RAND(),0) as FamigliaDiSconto,ROUND(RAND(),0) as CodMarca,ROUND(RAND(),0) as MoltiplicatorePrezzo,ROUND(RAND(),0) as codEAN,ROUND(RAND(),0) as IdArticolo from( SELECT ROUND(RAND(),0) as PrezzoListino,ROUND(RAND(),0) as FamigliaDiSconto,ROUND(RAND(),0) as CodMarca,ROUND(RAND(),0) as MoltiplicatorePrezzo,ROUND(RAND(),0) as codEAN,ROUND(RAND(),0) as IdArticolo,Codice as CodArt,Descrizione,UM,CostoUnitario as Prezzo,CEILING((SUM(Quantita/120))) AS Quantita, CostoUnitario*CEILING((SUM(Quantita/120))) as Totale FROM( /*Articoli */ SELECT 'A' as TipoArticolo,SottoCapitolo.Codice, SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura as UM, SottoCapitolo.Descrizione, SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario, SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita) AS Quantita, SUM(SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Totale FROM SottoCapitolo INNER JOIN Capitolo ON Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo  inner join Preventivo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  WHERE SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Articolo' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo  GROUP BY SottoCapitolo.Codice, SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura, SottoCapitolo.Descrizione, SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario  UNION ALL  /* Disitnte -- con articoli diversi da manodopera*/  SELECT Articolo.TipoArticolo,Articolo.CodArt as Codice, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita * (DistintaSemplice.Quantita)) as Quantita, cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo * (SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita))), 2) as numeric(12, 2)) as Totale  FROM Preventivo INNER JOIN Capitolo ON Capitolo.IdPreventivo = Preventivo.IdPreventivo  INNER JOIN SottoCapitolo   ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo   INNER JOIN Distinta ON SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta   INNER JOIN DistintaSemplice  ON DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta INNER JOIN Articolo ON Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo  WHERE Articolo.TipoArticolo != 'M' and SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo     GROUP BY  Articolo.TipoArticolo,Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo UNION ALL Select Articolo.TipoArticolo,Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, (SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Quantita, ((SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) * Articolo.Prezzo) / 60 as Totale from SottoCapitolo inner join Distinta on Distinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join SottoDistinta on SottoDistinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join DistintaSemplice on DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = SottoDistinta.CodiceSottoDistinta inner join Articolo on Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo inner join Capitolo on Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo inner join Preventivo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  where SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo  union all  /* Disitnte -- solo manodopera*/ SELECT Articolo.TipoArticolo,Articolo.CodArt as Codice, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita * (DistintaSemplice.Quantita / DistintaSemplice.Divisore)) as Quantita, (Articolo.Prezzo * (SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita * (DistintaSemplice.Quantita / DistintaSemplice.Divisore)))) as Totale FROM Preventivo  INNER JOIN Capitolo  ON Capitolo.IdPreventivo = Preventivo.IdPreventivo INNER JOIN SottoCapitolo   ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo  INNER JOIN Distinta  ON SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta INNER JOIN DistintaSemplice ON DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta INNER JOIN Articolo ON Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo WHERE Articolo.TipoArticolo = 'M' and SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo GROUP BY  DistintaSemplice.Divisore, Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.TipoArticolo,Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo UNION ALL Select Articolo.TipoArticolo,Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, (SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Quantita, (((SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) * Articolo.Prezzo)) as Totale from SottoCapitolo inner join Distinta on Distinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join SottoDistinta on SottoDistinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join DistintaSemplice on DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = SottoDistinta.CodiceSottoDistinta inner join Articolo on Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo inner join Capitolo on Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo inner join Preventivo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  where SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo)Q where Q.TipoArticolo='M' GROUP BY Codice,TipoArticolo, UM, Descrizione, CostoUnitario  union all SELECT Codice as CodArt,Descrizione,UM,CostoUnitario as Prezzo,SUM(Quantita) AS Quantita, CostoUnitario*(SUM(Quantita)) as Totale FROM( /*Articoli */ SELECT 'A' as TipoArticolo, SottoCapitolo.Codice, SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura as UM, SottoCapitolo.Descrizione, SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario, SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita) AS Quantita, SUM(SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Totale FROM SottoCapitolo INNER JOIN Capitolo ON Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo  inner join Preventivo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  WHERE SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Articolo' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo  GROUP BY SottoCapitolo.Codice, SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura, SottoCapitolo.Descrizione, SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario  UNION ALL  /* Disitnte -- con articoli diversi da manodopera*/  SELECT Articolo.TipoArticolo, Articolo.CodArt as Codice, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita * (DistintaSemplice.Quantita)) as Quantita, cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo * (SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita))), 2) as numeric(12, 2)) as Totale  FROM Preventivo INNER JOIN Capitolo ON Capitolo.IdPreventivo = Preventivo.IdPreventivo  INNER JOIN SottoCapitolo   ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo   INNER JOIN Distinta ON SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta   INNER JOIN DistintaSemplice  ON DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta INNER JOIN Articolo ON Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo  WHERE Articolo.TipoArticolo != 'M' and SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo     GROUP BY  Articolo.TipoArticolo, Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo UNION ALL Select Articolo.TipoArticolo, Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, (SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Quantita, ((SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) * Articolo.Prezzo) / 60 as Totale from SottoCapitolo inner join Distinta on Distinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join SottoDistinta on SottoDistinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join DistintaSemplice on DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = SottoDistinta.CodiceSottoDistinta inner join Articolo on Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo inner join Capitolo on Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo inner join Preventivo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  where SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo  union all  /* Disitnte -- solo manodopera*/ SELECT Articolo.TipoArticolo, Articolo.CodArt as Codice, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita * (DistintaSemplice.Quantita / DistintaSemplice.Divisore)) as Quantita, (Articolo.Prezzo * (SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita * (DistintaSemplice.Quantita / DistintaSemplice.Divisore)))) as Totale FROM Preventivo  INNER JOIN Capitolo  ON Capitolo.IdPreventivo = Preventivo.IdPreventivo INNER JOIN SottoCapitolo   ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo  INNER JOIN Distinta  ON SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta INNER JOIN DistintaSemplice ON DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = Distinta.CodiceDistinta INNER JOIN Articolo ON Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo WHERE Articolo.TipoArticolo = 'M' and SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo GROUP BY  DistintaSemplice.Divisore, Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.TipoArticolo, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo UNION ALL Select Articolo.TipoArticolo, Articolo.CodArt, Articolo.UM, Articolo.Descrizione, Articolo.Prezzo, (SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Quantita, (((SottoDistinta.Quantita * SottoCapitolo.Quantita) * Articolo.Prezzo)) as Totale from SottoCapitolo inner join Distinta on Distinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join SottoDistinta on SottoDistinta.CodiceDistinta = SottoCapitolo.CodiceDistinta inner join DistintaSemplice on DistintaSemplice.CodiceDistinta = SottoDistinta.CodiceSottoDistinta inner join Articolo on Articolo.IdArticolo = DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo inner join Capitolo on Capitolo.IdCapitolo = SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo inner join Preventivo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  where SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta' and Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo)Q where Q.TipoArticolo = 'A' GROUP BY Codice,TipoArticolo, UM, Descrizione, CostoUnitario)q)q2", nativeQuery = true)
List<Articolo> caricaArticoliPreventivo(@Param("IdPreventivo") int IdPreventivo);
```

**Spring boot error:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
could not extract ResultSet; 
SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**Articolo.java**

```
@Table(name = "Articolo")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Articolo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IdArticolo")
    private int idArticolo;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "CodMarca")
    private String codmarca;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "UM")
    private String um;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "CodArt")
    private String codart;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "PrezzoListino")
    private double prezzolistino;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "FamigliaDiSconto")
    private String famigliadisconto;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "Descrizione")
    private String descrizione;

    @Getter
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DataInserimento")
    private Date Data;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "Prezzo")
    private double prezzo;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "CodEAN", nullable = true)
    private BigInteger codEAN;

    @Column(name = "MoltiplicatorePrezzo", nullable = true)
    private Integer moltiplicatorePrezzo;

    public Articolo(String codArt, String descrizione, double prezzo) {
        this.codart = codArt;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }

    public Articolo(String CodMarca, String CodArt, String Descrizione, String UM, Double Prezzo, Double PrezzoListino, String Barcode, String FamigliaDiSconto, int MoltiplicatorePrezzo, BigInteger CodEAN) {
        this.codart = CodArt;
        this.codEAN = CodEAN;
        this.codmarca = CodMarca;
        this.descrizione = Descrizione;
        this.um = UM;
        this.prezzo = Prezzo;
        this.prezzolistino = PrezzoListino;
        this.famigliadisconto = FamigliaDiSconto;
        this.moltiplicatorePrezzo = MoltiplicatorePrezzo;
    }

}
```

I've verified the SQL query syntax, and it seems to be correct. Are there any nuances or configurations within Spring Boot that could be causing this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does your result from the query actually match the `Articolo` as that is what it it trying to map to. Try to do some formatting in the query as in its current form it is unreadable, in addition add the full stacktrace and not a snippet as the snippet doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have add articolo model

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question if the result of the query matches the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing a space: `select *from` should be `select * from`